# How to add react router Error together with private routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm using react and react-router v4 for routing. I have created PrivateRoutes for authentication and since I have implemented them I'm not able to use Error route for not matching.

Error route is working every time I hit the wrong page, but the problem is that it renders each time for any route.

I tried to create regular  but each page I Open it renders first and then after that, I see that as it should be

```
const Error = () => {
  console.log('error showing');
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Error: Route doesn't exist</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, token, error, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props => (
      token !== '' ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
    )}
  />
);


  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
          <Layout>
            <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Home} exact token={this.props.login.token} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/upload" component={Upload} exact token={this.props.login.token} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/certificates" component={Certs} exact token={this.props.login.token} />
            <Route component={Error} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/transactions" component={Tables} exact token={this.props.login.token} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/issue" component={Issue} token={this.props.login.token} />
            <Route component={Error}/>
          </Layout>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that you are rendering the Routes without any Switch case wrapping the PrivateRoutes. Since Layout component is rendering within the outer Switch statement if `/login` and `/signup` routes don't match, it will automatically be rendered without considering which PrivateRoute matches. So you need to wrap the Routes rendered as `children` to `Layout` component within `Switch` and have only one instance of `Error` route

A correct way of handling the PrivateRoutes would be as below.

```
render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
          <Layout>
           <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Home} exact token={this.props.login.token} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/upload" component={Upload} exact token={this.props.login.token} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/certificates" component={Certs} exact token={this.props.login.token} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/transactions" component={Tables} exact token={this.props.login.token} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/issue" component={Issue} token={this.props.login.token} />
            <Route component={Error}/>
           </Switch>
          </Layout>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
```